# JAXB with Ant: How to make XJCTask respect <depends>

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

we are using Jaxb with different schema files that include some common parts.
To build this we are using the Ant XJCTask from the JAXB distribution:

```
<xjc classpath="bin" removeOldOutput="yes" schema="main-schema.xsd" target="src" extension="true">
        <arg value="-no-header"/>
        <depends dir=".">
            <filename name="some/dir/included1.xsd"/>
            </depends>
        <produces dir=".">
            <include name="some/package/dir/*.java"/>
            </produces>
    </xjc>
```

But apparently the depends has no influence, as one can see running ant -verbose:

```
      [xjc] Checking timestamp of /local0/mginkel/workspace/main-schema.xsd
  [xjc] Checking timestamp of /local0/mginkel/workspace/some/package/dir/Generated1.java
  [xjc] Checking timestamp of /local0/mginkel/workspace/some/package/dir/Generated2.java
```

Is there a way to track the dependencies on the includes properly in ant. I only want to recompile
the bindings if necessary, but I definitely want to recompile if one of the includes has changed.
(this is what currently does not work).

Comment: Are you sure the xsd file exists where you are specifying?
The depends element works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `dir` setting is wrong. Here's the one we use at work (and it works for us):

```
<xjc schema="${xsd.location}/eviction.xsd" destdir="${src}"
  package="com.onsitemanager.eviction.schema">
  <produces dir="${src}/com/onsitemanager/eviction/schema" includes="*.java"/>
</xjc>
```

(Don't worry too hard about what the values of `${xsd.location}` and `${src}` are, as long as they're sensible for your setup with regard to where you store your .xsd files and source files, respectively.)

Of note is that `dir` is the directory where the .java files are being output to, and `includes` is simply `*.java`.

Comment: No, apparently it works in my way as well. I just used a similar format in the `produces` and in the `depends` rules to show that it does not behave the same. The directory to evaluate the paths in is finally the root project directory of ANT.